# How does nested iframes sandboxed work?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

If I have a page `A`, which has a sandboxed iframe `B`, `B` origin will be null, and `A` is say `mysite.com`, but `B` has a sandboxed iframe `C` (nested). `C` origin will be null too, but does that mean `C` can access `B`'s DOM because origin is same even though it's null?

Also note that `A`, `B`, `C` actual origin is all `mysite.com`.

Thanks

Comment: This seems pretty trivial to try out for yourself. Did you try?

Comment: MDN says "If `allow-same-origin` is not used, the embedded content is treated as being from a unique origin."